# Poisson Formula finding lamina?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

> A microprocessor manufacturing facility produces 300 microprocessors
>   per hour. The probability that an individual chip is faulty is 0.01.
>   Calculate the probability that in a given hour's production:
>
> a) Two chips are faulty

To find $\lambda$ I multiply

```
0.01*300 = 3
```

I am not sure though if I have to take the time into account(1 hour(60))?

Or if the question takes this into account.

Then finding P(2 microchips)

$3^2$* $e^{-3}$ / 2! = .22

But this seems awfully high to me 22% are my calculations off??

Comment: You have $300 \times 0.01$ as the rate per hour, so do you not have to take into account the "one hour" or if you do then multiply by $1$.  If you had wanted rate per day ($24$ hours) then it would be $300 \times 0.01 \times 24$

Comment: This is what I though thanks, but The final .22 seems very high to me dont you think?

Comment: $0.224$ looks fine to me.  By the way, the Greek letter is called *lambda* rather than *lamina* and is written $\lambda$

Comment: Cool thanks @Henry I have made the edits :)